# Install Laravel 5 on Openshift - gives blank page

Tags: openshift, laravel-5

I installed Laravel 5 on Openshift via Git. Hitting my app (the clean install) in a browser returns a blank page. Any idea what could be the cause?

Here is the URL: http://dev-rogercreasy.rhcloud.com/

Comment: check out logs by `rhc tail` command and let us know what is the output

Comment: The code is too long...

Comment: It basically says there is a fatal PHP error, failed opening autoload.php

Comment: looks like you need to run `composer install` or `composer dump-autoload`. you can try running it manually in appropriate dir (first you need to ssh in by `rhc ssh`) and if it fixes the problem, you can add it to some of the openshift hooks

Comment: I got 2 errors on composer install
 [RuntimeException]                                                           
  Could not load package dragonrun1/phpspec in http://packagist.org: [Unexpec  
  tedValueException] Could not parse version constraint ^1.0.1: Invalid versi  
  on string "^1.0.1"

Comment: and

 [UnexpectedValueException]                                                  
  Could not parse version constraint ^1.0.1: Invalid version string "^1.0.1"

Comment: I found a suggestion that I run `composer self-update` which I tried, it gave another error...
' [Composer\Downloader\FilesystemException]                                    
  Filesystem exception:                                                        
  Composer update failed: the "/var/lib/openshift/.cartridge_repository/redha  
  t-php/0.0.24/usr/bin/composer.phar" file could not be written  '

Comment: Is your Git repository public?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have old composer. I had the same error. To fix it go to your php dir and update composer.
In my case I gone to folder where placed my php.exe and ran command composer self-update:

`cd d:\work\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.5>D:\work\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP-5.5\ 
 composer self-update`

After it I gone back to folder with project and `composer install` command completed without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Laravel 5 QuickStart](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/115-laravel-5-0). The QuickStart uses a custom version of the standard OpenShift PHP 5.4 cartridge. The only difference is the included version of Composer has been updated.

Comment: Hi @luciddreamz, I got the same problem. After I was deploying my existing codes on openshift, the result only blank page. How do I check version of composer in the openshift?